# Enforcing version in maven

Tags: java, maven

Is it possible for a library to enforce a version of one of its dependency.

For example, In a library A, I am developing, I want to enforce a `hystrix-core` version using my library such that which ever project imports the library A, it's not able to override the `hystrix-core` version.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to do that. And you shouldn't. That's the **choice** and the **responsibility** of the project depending on you. If you're obsessed by your declared version, you can prepare havoc for your clients by packaging your lib as a fat jar and including `hystrix-core` in it.

Comment: An alternative route could be to fork the hystrix project, move all the code to a different package (like mine.histrix), and then have *your* code to depend on this version of hystrix.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele I understand the concerns, but hystrix has used abstract classes over interface, and if my overridden behavior fails to implement that it switches to default one rather than failing. That's what I cam concerned about.